# Online Accounts handled by Gnome

Tags: gnome, cloud, online-accounts

I am testing the Online Accounts feature provided by Gnome in its latest version. 
The issue is that when I open a file stored in my Google Drive and I work on it for a while, when I try to save it I get the following error:

```
Error saving the document 1ZMbivZcT_iv1lCSz81S3ToQL8eF0KZxS:

The object is not a directory.
```

After I open Nautilus, access the directory in the cloud in question and I am able to save to document successfully. For some reason the connection is closed and it cannot be resumed when trying to save a file. Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Thanks